# Where is the terminal for Polferries in Gdansk?

Tags: ferries, poland, gdansk

We're taking Polferries from Gdansk to Nynäshamn. According to our Web search, the ferry terminal could be on either side of the sea. Westerplatte or the other side. Which side is it? If the sea canal is vertically in the middle, is the terminal left or right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Majora Henryka Sucharskiego 70, 80-542 Gdańsk, Poland](https://www.google.se/maps/place/Majora+Henryka+Sucharskiego+70,+80-601+Gda%C5%84sk,+Poland/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x46fd0cb700fe77f3:0x5c23ec0890dfb09?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwito-O3l9fUAhUDR48KHapVDMIQ8gEILDAA). It is clearly on one side of the channel.

Source of the information is the Polferries official web-site: http://polferries.com/farja/faq/farjeterminaler